# Pydantic. How to add data alteration functions within the class

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am just starting to learn Pydantic and FastAPI. My model looks like this.

```
class Max70Text(BaseModel):
    __root__: constr(min_length=1,max_length=70) = Field(
        ...,
        description='Specifies a character string with a maximum length of 70 characters.'    
    )
```

If my string is of length more than 70 i handle the truncate function outside this class within my main program.
I would like to do this within the class itself just to keep things clean. Ie. If a string of length more than 70 is passed to this class then the object returned should automatically have its str value truncated from the right side to match the length.

Comment: Use a validator function and truncate the steering there.

Comment: Important point about using validators for this scenario: you need to add `pre=True` so that the validation happens before `max_length` is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [root_validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators) to parse incoming data according to your constraints:

```
class Max70Text(BaseModel):
    __root__: constr(min_length=1,max_length=70) = Field(
        ...,
        description='Specifies a character string with a maximum length of 70 characters.'
    )

    @staticmethod
    def truncate(v):
        return v[:70]

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def len_validator(cls, values):
        values['__root__'] = cls.truncate(values['__root__'])
        return values
```

In addition to [root types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) like above, pydantic allows you to create own [custom data types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types), in some situations it is more convenient. The demo is not production ready:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class TruncatedBase(str):
    limit: int

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def truncate(cls, value: str):
        return value[:cls.limit] + "..." if len(value) > cls.limit else value

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError('string required')
        if not v:
            raise TypeError('empty string is not allowed')
        return cls(cls.truncate(v))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Max{self.limit}Text({super().__repr__()})'


def truncated_text(limit=10):
    return type('TruncatedText', (TruncatedBase,), {'limit': limit})


class Model(BaseModel):
    field1: truncated_text(limit=5) = Field(..., description="5 max")
    field2: truncated_text(limit=6) = Field(..., description="6 max")


print(Model(field1="1"*6, field2="1"*6))
```

Output:

```
field1=Max5Text('11111...') field2=Max6Text('111111')
```